# Уменьшение размера файла при создании клона репозитория

Tags: git

Работаю над файлом в проекте, после завершения делаю комит в репозиторий. Далее мне нужно например сделать еще одну копию репозитория. Делаю клон. И сравниваю файлы. У первого размер 44,9 КБ, а в копии репозитория 44,0 кб. Текстовое содержимое одинаковое. Почему различается размер файлов при идентичном содержимом?

Comment: Уточните, какие конкретно файлы вы сравниваете? Дополните пример.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно в первом случае у Вас окончания строк [CRLF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8), а во втором LF. Git пытаеться оптимизировать и если в настройкая явно не указанно, конвертирует CRLF в LF. [core.autocrlf](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-Git)